# VB.net connect to database pop out 'Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 1''

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I was using vb.net and try to update the row of the sourcedata in the gridview which connected to the database.I'm using primary key id in the database.

Below is the related code,This is to generate the primary key ID:

```
 Private Sub GetId()
    Dim Id As Integer
    Dim query As String
    Dim nameid As Integer
    query = "select Id from information.information order by Id Desc"
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server =" + server + ";" + "user id=" + username + ";" _
        + "password=" + password + ";" + "database = " + database
    sqlConn.Open()
    sqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(query, sqlConn)
    sqlRd = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

    If (sqlRd.Read()) Then
        nameid = Integer.Parse(sqlRd(0)) + 1
        Id = nameid.ToString("00")
    ElseIf (Convert.IsDBNull(sqlRd)) Then
        Id = ("01")
    Else
        Id = ("01")
    End If
    sqlConn.Close()
    txtId.Text = Id
End Sub
```

This is to update the rows:

```
 Private Sub Editrow()
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server =" + server + ";" + "user id=" + username + ";" _
        + "password=" + password + ";" + "database = " + database
    sqlConn.Open()

    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn

    With sqlCmd
        .CommandText = "Update information.information set Name=@Name,EmailAddress=@EmailAddress,PhoneNumber=@PhoneNumber,DOB=@DOB,Address=@Address where Id=@newId"
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@newId", txtId)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", txtEmailAddress)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", txtPhoneNumber)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtDob)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress)
    End With

    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlConn.Close()
    updateTable()
    'clear txtbox values
    txtId.Text = ""
    txtName.Text = ""
    txtEmailAddress.Text = ""
    txtPhoneNumber.Text = ""
    txtDob.Text = ""
    txtAddress.Text = ""
End Sub
```

this is to get the rows:

```
Private Sub Getrow()
    Try
        txtId.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        txtName.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
        txtEmailAddress.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value
        txtPhoneNumber.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value
        txtDob.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value
        txtAddress.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

And here is the error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apaqx.png)
here is my database setting:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duA7R.png)

Comment: Don't try to re-use the same connection object throughout your app. ADO.Net has a feature called **connection pooling** that already handles connection re-use, and when you keep the same object you break this and make things worse, rather than better. Instead, create a new connection object for each query inside of a `Using` block, so it will always be promptly disposed. I know it seems wasteful to create so many object, but this really will perform better.

Comment: Please paste the exception message instead of the screenshot of it

Answer (score 1):

I am making the following assumption: txtId, txtName, txtEmailAddress, etc. are textboxes on a form.

In your code you currently are passing the Textbox object. I think if you pass the Text property of your textbox (ie txtName.Text) instead it will fix your issue.

```
   With sqlCmd
        .CommandText = "Update information.information set Name=@Name,EmailAddress=@EmailAddress,PhoneNumber=@PhoneNumber,DOB=@DOB,Address=@Address where Id=@newId"
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@newId", txtId.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", txtEmailAddress.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", txtPhoneNumber.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtDob.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text)
    End With
```